# TypeError: need string or buffer, list found

Tags: python, typeerror

I am working my way through *Learn Python the Hard Way* and am stuck on the extra credit for exercise 16. I am trying to read a file that I created using the main exercise 16. The code I wrote is as follows:

```
# pylint: disable-msg=C0103
""" This script reads and prints a file set from the argv """
from sys import argv

filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print txt.read()
```

The file I am trying to read is:

```
Derp Derp
Reading this file
Will it work?
```

I am receiving the error: *TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found* but am unsure how my file is a list rather than strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To debug, try printing `filename`

Comment: Wow, thanks! By printing filename, I discovered that filename was an array, or I suppose Python calls it a list? Anyways, I finished unpacking argv by changing `filename = argv` to `script, filename = argv` and everything worked swimmingly. I appreciate you teaching me to cook rather than just feeding me.

Answer (score 3):

`argv` is a list of arguments to your script. The first argument is `argv[1]`. Try this:

```
from sys import argv

txt = open(argv[1])

print txt.read()
```

---

**Important note:** almost always the first item in a list is the `0`th item, `argv` is an exception because the `0`th argument is your script name.

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't know thats how argv worked, I alternatively  changed `filename = argv` to `script, filename = argv`. I appreciate this answer and only chose dbr's as the correct one as I'll be able to use that one as inspiration in debugging future problems I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same error but solved it with this code:

```
from sys import argv

txt = open(argv[1])

print txt.read()
```